# Resolve HTTPS alias routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm currently deploying an AWS based static website and i'm running into some difficulty when trying to route HTTPS traffic for alias domains. Right now I have a simple website (in development) under the website https://spirited.studio which is running through CloudFront. I setup health monitors through Route 53 to verify the website is live and I see the following:

[image: health monitors]

Does anyone have any idea how to correct the https://www.* routing? I've tried setting up CNAMEs for the www.* address, additional buckets, secondary CloudFront Distributions, another Route 53 Hosted Zone and Record Sets but I'm just not quite hitting the mark. The https:// works perfectly for non www.* addresses, and I properly get redirected with a 301 on http:// queries so I'm unsure what might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is add a secondary domain in the distribution configuration:

Change its value to www.spirited.studio,spirited.studio and it should work.

Then after this update your Route 53 Hosted Zone to have its www record target this CloudFront Distribution

Comment: This resolved it perfectly. It's also a good idea to setup a second bucket with http redirect requests to your www/non-www site and setup an alias record within Route 53 under this bucket. This just ensures if someone ends up on a secondary domain then they get routed to the main domain.